# Get cookie in Blazor .NET 8 before first render

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

After migrating my Blazor .Net6 project to .Net8 my cookie management is broken and I can't find a way around it.

Due to theming and avoiding FOUC I need to access a cookie in the HTTP request before first render. Naively I have tried storing the cookie in a scoped `ThemeService` injected in the root `App` component, since only the root can access the `HttpContext` as a `CascadingParameter`. However, the same `ThemeService` injected into any other page or component will just instantiate a *second* scoped service... I'm using RenderMode.InteractiveServer with prerender disabled globally at the HeadOutlet/Router level, by the way.

My theory is that the DI scope of the root `App` component is based on the original **HTTP request**, while all other component DI scopes are based on the **Blazor SignalR** connection which is only established later.

So my question is: *How can I pass cookie data from the first scope to the other, before my components render?*

The only thing I can think of is creating a Singleton service where I store a dictionary of IP/cookie or similar, insert it from the root `App` component and then somehow get hold of the IP from SignalR and look it up in the Singleton. Is that even possible/viable? I'd really appreciate any help or input on this one, it seems so basic but I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the browser is not blocking your cookies? Iblogged about that here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. Injecting the state container directly into the `App` component never worked out for me; it always instantiates in non-user-scope and never re-initializes, so the persist pattern is not viable.

Eventually I just stored the cookie as a regular member of the App component and transferred it by normal parameter binding to a child component. That child component does render in user-scope, so I was able to inject the state container there.

It's not as clean and reusable as I would have liked, but at least it works.

Comment: Apparently the same workaround was suggested here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/31691#issuecomment-1937358269

Comment: I use an "Enter Site" button for unregistered users, or the landing screen for registered users.  If unregistered, I check for cookies, and add them to a scoped state service.  If registered, I load persistent data from my DB.  This initial UI interaction is very useful for mobile devices-- you can set up preloading of sounds, establish a video context, get microphone permissions, etc. etc.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Even with a landing page I want that page/button themed, so I still need the theme cookie before first render. See the link above as to why scoped services can't be used in the root App component in .Net 8 style projects.

Comment: Can you not access the cookie in Middleware?  I don't think you should really need a service if you just need it at initialization.  ( suppose there's no more _Host.cshtml where you can access the HTTP context during init in .net 8, right?)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 No, there's no way to access it in "Middleware", which is practically Blazor anyway. The HTTP context is only available in the app root component, _Host.cshml is gone. The issue is not getting hold of the cookie itself, but tying it to a user session.

Comment: Middleware allows you to insert business logic in the app pipeline BEFORE the Blazor page is built, and it gives access to the HTTP context.  You can (for example) check if a user is authenticated and set state in a service.  I use it, for example, to create in my SQL database a guest user if someone isn't logged in, so they can play games on my ESL site without having to register first.  Then I log them in and pass the modified request on to Blazor.  If you don't take the time to learn about MIddleware, you're losing a great chance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
@page "/"
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

CookieVal:@data

@code{

    [CascadingParameter]

    public HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }

    private string data;

    private PersistingComponentStateSubscription persistingSubscription;


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
        if (httpContext is not null)
        {

            var existTargetCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("CookieKey", out data);
        }
        else
        {
            if(ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<string>(
            "Cookie", out data))
            {
                StateContainer.Property = data;
            }
            else
            {
                data = StateContainer.Property;
            }
        }
        persistingSubscription =
        ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(PersistData);
    }

    private Task PersistData()
    {
        ApplicationState.PersistAsJson("Cookie", data);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        persistingSubscription.Dispose();
        StateContainer.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
    
}


public class StateContainer
{
    private string? savedString;

    public string Property
    {
        get => savedString ?? string.Empty;
        set
        {
            savedString = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action? OnChange;

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's a valiant effort, thank you! I forgot to mention that I already tried the Persist pattern, but in my experiment App never re-rendered in user context, or at all for that matter... Did you manage to render it in user context by simply StateHasChanged() during PersistData?! I'll investigate and return!

Comment: I once tried CookieVal:@StateContainer.Property,In my opinion,We need PersistentComponentState to presist the data in http ,after the signalr connection has established,we need a scoped service(StateContainer) to hold the value

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why Microsoft has made it so hard to perform basic tasks in Blazor.

Comment: By the way, I had no luck with this. Yes, I can access the cookie in the App component, but I still have not found a good way to transfer it to a user-scoped service.